# R: standard errors

Tags: r

Is there any function to calculate Newey–West estimator and the White's standard errors in R in an NLS regression. The sandwich and car package do it but they need an lm 
object to calculate the error's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example taken from [Achim Zeleis's April 2013 r-help posting](http://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help//2013-April/350986.html) (which is, by the way, the *first* hit on Googling "nls sandwich"):

```
 ## from ?nls:
 x <- -(1:100)/10
 y <- 100 + 10 * exp(x / 2) + rnorm(x)/10
 suppressWarnings(nlmod <- nls(y ~  Const + A * exp(B * x)))

 vcov(nlmod)
 sqrt(diag(vcov(nlmod)))
```

From Achim's answer:

```
 ## the sandwich (aka HC0) covariance matrix and standard errors
 library("sandwich")
 sandwich(nlmod)
 sqrt(diag(sandwich(nlmod)))

 ## associated coefficient tests
 library("lmtest")
 coeftest(nlmod)
 coeftest(nlmod, vcov = sandwich)
```

Comment: Hi Ben thanks for the answer. I was also wondering how to perform this for a dataset in a panel data form